# How do I use a jenkins declarative pipeline credential and convert to a powershell credential?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

How do I use a jenkins declarative pipeline credential and convert to powershell credential?

Using

```
 environment {
       APPLICATION_SERVER_CRED = credentials('app-cred')
 }
```

simply using the converted secure strings does not appear to work well since PSCredential constructor is expecting different types : String and SecureString

```
PSCredential(String, SecureString)
```

How do I take the environment variables that were created by jenkins pipeline

```
$ENV:APPLICATION_SERVER_CRED_USR
$ENV:APPLICATION_SERVER_CRED_PSW
```

and convert them into variables that I can then pass into the PSCredential constructor of System.Management.Automation.PSCredential?

Within the powershell script, the types of the two environment variables when running

```
($ENV:APPLICATION_SERVER_CRED_USR).GetType()
```

is

```
System.String
```

which wont work directly, since the constructor expects different types.

If jenkins did not convert the username to secure text, I would not have this problem since I would convert password to secure string and satisfy the contructor argument for  PSCredential. But since they are secure text ( and type System.String), I cannot.

How can I convert the variables to create a PSCredential?

Comment: Perhaps I can convert masked text into secure string?

Answer (score 2):

oh kay, Yeah that was easier than I thought. I guess masked text literally just masks it from being visible in UI. This works.

```
$backendServerPass = ConvertTo-SecureString $ENV:APPLICATION_SERVER_CRED_PSW -AsPlainText -Force
$backendServerCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($ENV:APPLICATION_SERVER_CRED_USR, $backendServerPass) -Verbose
```

Comment: I am unable to get this to work: i keep getting the masked value `****` instead of the actual value. So my new cred comes out like: 
```
[Pipeline] echo
 
 UserName                        Password
 --------                        --------
 **** System.Security.SecureString
```